# Not launching from Eclipse to debug

Tags: android, eclipse

I need help...I don't have much hair left to pull out.

I use Eclipse and I use the "Project Explorer"...
I am no longer able to launch my app. It now tells me it is having errors but not marking anything with a red X other than title. It calculates up to Launching App name 100% then says there are errors. any time I change anything and save it the x on the disappears, so I attempt to run it and comes back with the red X and error that there are errors, but I have no clue. I even deleted everything I added to put it back to the last launchable version and even that isn't working.

I have no clue how to read the log cat or the error log.

I tried cleaning the project but the same thing as above happens.

This makes no sense...there is even an R.java file. I have no clue where to even look for an error or how to find it...

Please help...I'm sure this something simple that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Problems view open and visible? It will list all build/compile errors.

Comment: I don't know. I don't know how to see that.

Comment: I think I found that view. There is nothing showing under errors for that app. I app a few warnings but they are all about missing descriptions for ImageView

Comment: Yes This helped. THANK YOU!!!! Once I found the problems view and then tried again to debug the app an error appeared about an expired debug certificate. I found what to do about that and now I back in business.    THANK YOU again....